# How to open and close the registry it by time

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I have a web site to register.
How to use JavaScript for close and open registry it by time .
Open from 08:00 am to 16:00 pm.
Close from 16:01 pm to 07:59 am.
How to use JavaScript for disable all elements like input, button or all form.
Please help me .
Thanks a lot.

Comment: This logic probably should be on the server side as any blocked elements can be bypassed. If you just want to visually block forms just request some selector that will get all relevant inputs and flag them disabled. But that won't stop someone from enabling them back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can include this code:

```
var disableOrEnableRegistry = function(disableAll){
  //assuming need to disable all buttons and input 
  var buttons =document.getElementsByTagName('button');
  var inputs =document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(button of buttons){
      button.disabled = disableAll;
  } 
  for(input of inputs){
    input.disabled = disableAll;
  }
}

var toggleEnablingRegistry=function(toggle, interval, chechTimeCallback){
  setTimeout(function() {  
      disableOrEnableRegistry(toggle);
      chechTimeCallback(chechTimeCallback);
  }, interval);
}

var checkTime = function(callback){
  var d = new Date(); 
  var hours = d.getHours();
  var minutes = d.getMinutes();
  var seconds = d.getSeconds();
  if(hours>16 || (hours === 16 && minutes > 0)){ //16:01-23:59
      disableOrEnableRegistry(true);
      var remainingHours=23-hours+7;
      var remainingMinutes=60-minutes;
      var remainingSeconds=60-seconds;
      var remainingTimeInMiliseconds=(remainingHours*3600+remainingMinutes*60+remainingSeconds)*1000;
      toggleEnablingRegistry(false, remainingTimeInMiliseconds, callback);
  }
  else if(hours<8){//00:00-7:59
      disableOrEnableRegistry(true);
      var remainingTimeInMiliseconds=(hours*3600+minutes*60+seconds)*1000;
      toggleEnablingRegistry(false, remainingTimeInMiliseconds, callback);
  }
  else{//8:00-16:00
      var remainingHours=23-hours+7;
      var remainingMinutes=60-minutes;
      var remainingSeconds=60-seconds;
      var remainingTimeInMiliseconds=(remainingHours*3600+remainingMinutes*60+remainingSeconds)*1000;
      toggleEnablingRegistry(true, remainingTimeInMiliseconds, callback);
  }
}
checkTime(checkTime);
```

Explanation:
"checkTime()" function determines the current time is whether to disable or enable registry; Then it sends the next time when the register should be enabled or disabled by calling "toggleEnablingRegistry()" function which after the remaining time call the "checkTime()" function again.